# how to get program to terminate when user types in "exit" in C

Tags: c

When I type in "exit" the program doesn't seem to terminate from my code below; is there something I am missing or is there better way to terminate the program when the user types "exit"?

In my code you can also see it terminates when an EOF occurs this works properly, it just does not terminate when I type in "exit".

MY CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h> 
#include <string.h>

int main () {
   char input[512];
   char * charp;
   int len = 0;

   printf("> ");
   if(fgets(input, 512, stdin) == 0 || input == "exit") {    /* reads in input from user no more than 512 chars including null terminator*/
     printf("exitting program");
       exit(0);
   }

   printf("You entered: %s", input);
   len = strlen(input);

    charp = strtok(input, "  ' '\t"); /* splits the string on delimiters space '' and tab*/
    while (charp != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", charp);
        charp = strtok(NULL, "  ' '\t"); 
    }

   printf("The len of input = %d ", len);

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: `input == "exit"` does not do a string comparison but a comparison of the pointers to the first element. `"exit"` is a string literal and has a completely different address from the stack variable `input`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> input == "exit"

Is wrong. It should be `strcmp(input,"exit")==0`, otherwise you compare the address of the inputted string to the address of the string "exit" in memory, not the contents.

Make sure you remove the newline from your `fgets` call first, or use `strncmp(input, "exit", 4)`

Comment: i just tried that with this line -> if(fgets(input, 512, stdin) == 0 || strcmp(input, "exit") == 0) { 

that still didn't seem to work any ideas why?? @JCWasmx86

Comment: Don't forget [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input/28462221#28462221)

Comment: @JamesTierney - use `strncmp(input, "exit", 4)` instead.

Comment: Our job here isn't to completely fix people's broken programs.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica that worked thanks can you explain what this does im a bit of a beginner when it comes to C

Comment: can anyone explain to me how the line below works:

strncmp(input, "exit", 4) == 0

Comment: @JamesTierney It means, it compares the first `4` chars of the input with the second argument: `"exit"`

Comment: The size `4` tells the function only to check 4 charcters, not the newline that follows.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strncmp.htm

Comment: @RobertHarvey your fix won't work if "exitt" is entered.

Comment: Then just add `(strlen(input)==4&&(strncmp(input,"exit",4)==0))` @WeatherVane

Comment: @JCWasmx86 there is a newline: the length is not 4.